# onClick, load an iframe into a different div

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

Goal:

Clicking on a div loads an iFrame (with external website linked) into a central div. While clicking on navigation links will load my other html content into that central div.

I'm trying to avoid using iFrames for SEO reasons... Just need it this one time to load an external webpage.

Any thoughts? I've been racking my brain trying to find an answer with Google.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `src` attribute from the `iframe` tag and use the following:

```
<iframe id='someID' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="500" height="500">
```

And for the `onClick`, you can do something like this:

```
onClick='document.getElementById("someID").src="somepage.html";'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Amal! That worked great. I don't have enough reputation points to vote you up, sorry.